# Generate a Swagger spec from an API

Tags: api, swagger

I've build an API onto our Meteor backend, using Restivus. I would like to document it using Swagger, but the API is generated from MongoDB collections.

I would like to 'read' all the endpoints, and then generate a static Swagger file. Then I will update it from there. Is this possible?

eg: pass it something like :

```
http://servername.com/api/v1
```

And receive a listing of all available endpoints?

Comment: any findings to share on this topic? :D

Comment: No pretty much gave up on it ...

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/meteor-rest
That community is pretty much Restivus & Swagger :) For existing API try out restivus-swagger. If you start out by designing Swagger spec, try out generator-restivus, that scaffolds Restivus from swagger spec. Please open Github issues if any problems, I follow up to help & fix bugs :)